# How to calculate NRR from the list of dictionaries?

Tags: python, python-3.x, enumerate

I'm trying to calculate Net run rate for the list containing dictionaries 
suppose if list is

```
 score = [{'dismissal': 'run out (Hardik Pandya)', 'balls': '92', 'name': 'Amla', 'fours': '5', 'six': '0', 'runs': '71'}, {'dismissal': 'c Kohli    b Bumrah', 'balls': '32', 'name': 'Markram(c)', 'fours': '4', 'six': '1', 'runs': '32'}, {'dismissal': 'c Rohit    b Hardik Pandya', 'balls': '5', 'name': 'Duminy', 'fours': '0', 'six': '0', 'runs': '1'}..........]
```

I'm trying to calculate NRR for these valuese which are dynamic they keep changing, I tried using enumerate but I can't figure out how to proceed further

```
  dic= {k+str(i): v for i, x in enumerate(score, 1) for k, v in x.items()}
```

this will add indexes to the key of a dictionary how can I proceed after this, is there any other way its possible to achieve this?
By the way, to calculate NRR formula is = (runs/balls)*100, any assistance will be helpful.

expecting to get like this

```
dic = [{'dismissal1': 'run out (Hardik Pandya)', 'balls1': '92', 'name1': 'Amla', 'fours1': '5', 'six1': '0', 'runs1': '71','NRR1':'19.3'}, {'dismissal2': 'c Kohli    b Bumrah', 'balls2': '32', 'name2': 'Markram(c)', 'fours2': '4', 'six2': '1', 'runs2': '32','NRR2':'44.3'}, {'dismissal3': 'c Rohit    b Hardik Pandya', 'balls3': '5', 'name3': 'Duminy', 'fours3': '0', 'six3': '0', 'runs3': '1','NRR3':'45.3'}..........]
```

Comment: One thing at a time: how are they changing? If the problem is only the computation over the list, why not something like: 
[int(i['runs'])/int(i['balls']) for i in score]

Comment: I'm getting these values from cricket library module the list goes on I have put only a  part of it. I can't do separately as you suggested that my mistake I should've said properly

Comment: Cricket library module? Whatever that is, if it is a generator then you can make it piece by piece, otherwise you should tell better the output for any help we can bring...